# Find the sum of power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, self-learning

I have to find the sum of the following sequence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n-1},\quad x\geq0$$ and

How am I supposed to start?

Thanks.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Power_series), the power series: $-\log(1-x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$

Comment: is this the answer? how did you get that?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Multiply by $x$ and take the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

So what @RobertIsrael means is that look at $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+1}$, let's look at 
$$g(x) = xf(x) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} $$
Differentiating, you get 
$$g'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$$
Now integrate 
$$g(x) =  xf(x) =\int  \frac{x}{1-x} = -x-\ln\left(\left|x-1\right|\right)$$
then divide by $x$
$$f(x)  = -1-\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\left|x-1\right|\right)$$

Comment: @JaneSecuiu you tell me

Comment: Guys this is why you shouldn't answer PSQs. You're wasting your time *and* the time of those who are going to delete them later on as they keep coming, encouraged by those who give out answers.

Comment: what is a PSQ @ArnaudMortier

Comment: What *should* be encouraged is for the OP to think by themselves, that's a real piece of hard work especially when all they need to do is to wait for somebody to give out an answer, which ironically they can't even understand.

Comment: PSQ is Problem Statement Question, a question with no efforts, no context, just homework problem as it is stated.

Comment: how did you know @ArnaudMortier ?